# How to avoid reading index page, acknowledgement page, etc while reading a pdf file using pdf readers like PyPDF2

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I am using PyPDF2 to read a pdf files. Total pages in each PDF files is atleast 100. My end goal to read the 'main content' of pdf files, I mean I don't want to read content page, acknowledgement page etc. I just want to skip to the main content of the file.

```
# importing required modules
import PyPDF2

# creating a pdf file object
pdfFileObj = open(r"/content/IFA Manual 2020.pdf", 'rb')

# creating a pdf reader object
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)

document=''
for i in range(0,pdfReader.numPages):
    # creating a page object
    pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(i)
    # extracting text from page
    document=document+pageObj.extractText()

# closing the pdf file object
pdfFileObj.close()

document = document.replace('\n', '')
document
```

The response is as follows:

```
 i IFA MANUAL 2020         Controller General of Defence Accounts  Ulan Batar Road, Palam, Delhi Cantt – 11001   ii  iii CONTENTS   Chapter  Para  Subject  Page  1  Background and Origin of the IFA System  1-5  1.1 Introduction  1  1.2 Broad Charter of the Duties of IFA s 1  1.3 Introduction of IFA System in Service HQ  2  1.3.1  IFA System in Army  2  1.3.2  Present Structure of IFAs in Army  3  1.3.3  IFA System in Navy  3  1.3.4  Present Structure of IFAs in Navy  3  1.3.5  IFA System in Air Force  4  1.3.6  Present structu re of IFAs in IAF  4  1.3.7  IFA System in Border Roads Organisation  4  1.4 Expectations from IFAs  5 2  Role & Functions of PIFA / IFA  6-9  2.1 Introduction  6  2.2 AON Stage  6  2.2.1  IFA is to vet the quantities indented  7  2.3 Tendering stage  7  2.4 Expenditure Sanction Stage  7  2.5 Post Contract Management  8  2.5.2  Other Duties of the IFA  8 3  General Concepts of Public Procurement and the Role of the IFA  10-24  3.1 Introduction  10  3.2 Standards (Canons) of Financial Propriety  10  3.3 Basic Aims of Procurement (Five R's)  11  3.4 Refined Concepts of Cost Value  12  3.5 Fundamental Principles of Public Procurement  12  3.6 Policy Guidelines  14  3.7 Decentralization and Delegation of Powers  15   iv     Chapter  Para  Subject  Page   3.8 Types of Pr ocurement  15  3.8.1  Capital Procurement  15  3.8.2  Revenue Procurement  15  3.8.3  Indigenous Procurement  16  3.8.4  Foreign Procurement (Import)  16  3.8.5  Central Procurement  16  3.8.6  Local Procurement  16  3.8.7  Procurement from Ordnance Factories and  PSUs 
 1 Chapter -1 Background and Origin of the IFA System   1.1 The concept of the Integrated Financial Advice System was introduced in the Ministries and Departments of the Government of India in the wake of the decision on Departm entalisation of Accounts in 1976. The scheme of Integrated Financial Adviser was detailed in Office Memorandum No - 10(29) -E.Coord./73 dated 06.10.75. The scheme provided that the Financial Adviser would be responsible both to the administrative Ministry/De partment and the Ministry of Finance. The Ministry of Finance has revised the charter of Financial Advisers vide OM No. 5(6)/L&C/2006 dated 01.06.2006. The main aim of the scheme was to make available financial expertise to the executive authorities, exped ite decision making in all matters involving financial rules and regulations and to ensure that all expenditure proposals are subjected to financial scrutiny before according approval by the Competent Authority. The responsibilities envisaged for the finan cial Advisers must be accompanied by corresponding empowerment and capacity, both individually and institutionally for meeting the emerging challenges.
```

we can see the index page is also read. How to avoid reading index page. since I will be using lot of pdfs so there is no fixed page upto which index is there. Just wanted to know is there some smart way to avoid reading index, acknowledge page etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way that will always work. You need some heuristics + have PDFs that are somehow well structured. Or you start a machine learning project for document categorization (NLP).

But if you want to look purely at what PDF offers you, I have two ideas.

### Idea 1: page_labels

You can use the page labels to figure out where the real content begins:

`reader.page_labels` is a list of strings. You might be lucky and the first parts might have roman labels such as "i", "ii", "iii, "iv", ...

The "real content" then begins at "1".

See https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/PdfReader.html#pypdf.PdfReader.page_labels

### Idea 2: outline (bookmarks)

You can use the `reader.outline` to jump to the first (or second) element.

See https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/PdfReader.html#pypdf.PdfReader.outline